# Print list items with Java streams

Tags: java, java-8

I can use something like:

```
 .forEach(System.out::print)
```

...to print my list items but if I have another operation to do before printing I can't use it like:

```
mylist.replaceAll(s -> s.toUpperCase()).forEach(System.out::print)
```

I'm getting an error:

> void cannot be dereferenced

Comment: And the question is? (btw, you can use a stream and map)

Comment: The question is what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have to decide. When you want to modify the list, you can’t combine the operations. You need two statements then.

```
myList.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);// modifies the list
myList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

If you just want to `map` values before printing without modifying the list, you’ll have to use a `Stream`:

```
myList.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print and save modified values simultaneously you can do

```
List<String> newValues = myList.stream().map(String::toUpperCase)
.peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to print all of them in one go is

Arrays.toString(list.toArray())

Comment: `Arrays.toString(list.toArray())` produces the same result as `list.toString()`, but the latter doesn’t require copying the entire contents into a temporary array.

Comment: List.toString() does not exist in Java 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: @Matt *every* object has a [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method. That’s so fundamental that you don’t need to spell it out, `"" + list` will implicitly invoke `toString()` on `list`, likewise `System.out.println(list);` will do. Even the `Arrays.toString(…)` method of this post says in [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-): “*The value returned by this method is equal to the value that would be returned by `Arrays.asList(a).toString()`, …*”.

Comment: @Holger That certainly compiles, and thank you for the lecture, but if Object doesn't know how to iterate through a list and print all of the individual values, wouldn't you just get <class>@<hashcode>? The bit that I missed is that ArrayList inherits from AbstractCollection, and AbstractCollection.toString() is what ends up being invoked.

Comment: @Holger However, the question did not say what kind of List they were working with. Implement your own List, without a toString() method, and myList.toString() will simply print `com.whatever.MyList@xxxxxxxx`.

Comment: @Matt I don’t know of any real life `List` implementation that doesn’t have a conforming `toString()` implementation. Even implementers not thinking about such details will likely just extend `AbstractList` and get `toString()` for free. Using an expensive copying approach to handle a hypothetical case, is not the right approach. Instead, fix your custom collections if you forgot to add a `toString()` method.

Comment: @Holger I hope you're right about people doing the right thing. I've learned the hard way not to assume things like that when helping others troubleshoot their problems. Cheers!

Comment: If it is a list of objects, toString() will be ignored and if there is no default print functionality for the objects, it will simply print the address information for the object.

Comment: completely agree with @Matt's point here, had the exact same thing as he mentioned,

I just wanted to see the list as it is (which is comprised of its own new class) and not the class with hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you had generated the `toString()` method for the class type your printing like  :

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "YourClassName{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", info='" + info + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

then   `System.out.println(listObj);` should print the result list of objects as :

```
[YourClassName{name='Muller', age=40, info='Sr.Developer'}, YourClassName{name='Zoe', age=34, info='Sr.Developer'}, YourClassName{name='Ghai', age=89, info='Principal Developer'}]
```

Comment: This is true if the list object inherits from AbstractCollection for its toString() method, or implements its own toString().

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the original values, but rather just capitalize the printed output, you can do this:

```
list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following example that can be executed in java8 environment.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // create a list
        List<String> mylist = Arrays.asList("Hello","World");
        mylist.stream()
              .map(String::toUpperCase)
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

/*output
HELLO
WORLD
*/
```