# How to print a nested list using java stream where the Object holds a list of references to itself

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, tostring

I have an object which looks similar to what's shown below:

```
public class Obj {
  private List<Obj> objs;
  private String objId;

  public List<Obj> getObjs() {
    return objs;
  }

  public String getobjId() {
    return objId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Obj [objs=" + objs + ", objId=" + objId + "]";
  }

}
```

How can I print the list of `objId` using streams?

EDIT

`Obj` can contain a list of Obj and it's children can contain a list of obj objects. If the depth is 5 levels, is it possible to print all the objId values from the top most obj to the values of the child at 5th level. I want to avoid nested for loops.

Comment: The easy way to print the list is to not use streams:  Just print the result of `toString()` should do it.

Comment: @markspace each of obj objects can have many children and if I just do toString() from the primary level of obj, I wouldn't be able to see the values of the child objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print list items with java 8 api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432948/print-list-items-with-java-8-api)

Comment: In that case `Obj` must override `toString()` to print its nested components, and so on ad infinitum.  There's no way to avoid nested loops, streams or otherwise, if you don't.

Comment: If you have `toString()` properly overridden, it should just print.  If it doesn't produce a proper test and show us the result.  Likely a bug in the `toString()` somewhere.

Comment: @markspace I have all the getters setters and the toString generated by the IDE. I have updated the code here with the toString method I have got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use recursion. One possible way to do it with streams is as follows:

```
private Stream<Obj> allObjs() {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(this), 
        objs == null ? Stream.empty() : objs.stream().flatMap(Obj::allObjs));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return allObjs()
        .map(Obj::getobjId)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Note that this works well as long as your `Obj` instances are arranged in a tree-like structure. If you have a specific `Obj` instance that is both a parent at some level and a child in some lower level (i.e. if your `Obj` instances form a graph), this solution won't work and you'll get a huge `StackOverflowError`.

---

If you can't modify the `Obj` class, you could achieve the same with helper methods that receive an instance of `Obj` i.e. in a `ObjService` class:

```
public static Stream<Obj> allObjs(Obj o) {
    if (o == null) return Stream.empty(); // in case the argument is null
    return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(o), 
            o.getObjs() == null ?
                Stream.empty() :
                o.getObjs().stream().flatMap(ObjService::allObjs));
}

public static String deepToString(Obj o) {
    return ObjService.allObjs(o)
        .map(Obj::getobjId)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Comment: Is there any workaround if I cannot make any modifications to the Class obj and I have to achieve this using a method in a service class?

Comment: I get a compilation error at line `.map(this::getobjId)` which is `The type Obj does not define getobjId(Obj) that is applicable here`

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that :) updated code printed `[[obj1]],[[obj2]]` when I did `System.out.println(objList.toString())`.  obj1 has a child obj1Child and obj2 has a child obj2Child. They were not printed.

Comment: `objList.stream().forEach(o ->{System.out.println(deepToString(o));});` prints obj1, and obj2 which are the immediate children of objList. If I run the same command is there a way it could print obj3 and obj4 , which are the children of obj1 and obj2? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I found I wasn't setting up the ObjList correctly. You solution works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using `Stream` you can start from here:

```
objs.stream().
            map(Obj::getObjId).
            forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

And improving a little bit:

```
    List<String> collect = objs.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) // Filter only nonNull objects. Avoid NullPointerException
            .map(Obj::getObjId)
            .peek(System.out::println) // Print the ObjId value from Obj
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Return the result to a List, if you need.
```

Now you have the basic way to get values from children. Learn a little about `Stream` and improve the code example ;)

Some nice links:

- [A Guide to Streams in Java 8](https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/)
- [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)
- [The Java 8 Stream API Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reason I want to use streams is to avoid nested for loops. If the obj object has children at 4 levels, If I use for each from the first level it would give me the children of the first level.

Comment: @Rosa14 maybe this answer can solve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30611899/6689024

Comment: This gives me the objIds of the first list

Comment: @Rosa14 I improved my answer with more examples and some nice links ;) I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you :) Should that be a flatMap instead of map because it's a nested list?

Comment: I think so :) But be careful with possible null values from some objs. So use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to avoid NullPointerException.